# Clojure read-line error "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number"

Tags: clojure, readline

I need to input a number using read-line:

```
(def x (read-line))
user => 1
```

gives the error:

CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code alone won't cause that error.

`read-line` returns a String, and I'm guessing you're trying to use `x` in the context where a number is expected.

To reproduce the error, you could do:

```
(def x (read-line)) ; Enter 1
(+ 1 x) ; Same as (+ 1 "1"), which should make the problem obvious

ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.add (Numbers.java:128)
```

Change it to use `Long/parseLong` (or a similar function):

```
(def x (Long/parseLong (read-line)))
```

You need to parse `x` as a number (`Long` in this case) before it can be used as a number.

```
(def x (Long/parseLong (read-line)))
(+ 1 x)

=> 2
```

Of course though, `Long/parseLong` will throw if you try to have it parse something that can't be represented as a number. In the real world, you'll want to do proper error handling via `try`.